# ExtJS send value to window

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new at ExtJS, i try send value with a button to a new window , I did some example, they are not working, in this example I think , I almost done, but this didn't work too, What is my wrong or wrongs?

```
var win = function (msg) { 
        Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
        title: msg,
        ...// here my window
    }); this.show;
};

    var btnAction = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Add Something',
        listeners: {
            click: function() {
                var rec = grid4.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                if (rec) {
                    win(rec.get('price'));
                } else {
                    alert('Please select a company from the grid');
                };}}
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.show` is a function. Functions are executed like this: `this.show();`

Watch out because now you can click 10 times on the same button and each time opening a new window... don't know if that's what you want..

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/Qh3CH/)

```
var win = function (msg) {
    var win = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
        title: msg
        // here my window
    });
    win.show();
    return win;
};

var btnAction = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Add Something',
    listeners: {
        click: function () {
            var rec = grid4.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
            if (rec) {
                win(rec.get('price'));
            } else {
                alert('Please select a company from the grid');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you're trying to do with that `price` after sending it to the window. But you can use `up()` and `down()` methods to access a field in that window.

For example

```
var btnAction = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Add Something',
        listeners: {
            click: function() {
                var rec = grid4.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                if (rec) {
                    win.down('textfield[name=priceField]').setValue(rec.get('price'));
                } else {
                    alert('Please select a company from the grid');
                };}}
    });
```

Also, any reason you're creating your window this way?

```
var win = function (msg) { 
        Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
        title: msg,
        ...// here my window
    }); this.show;
};
```

I'd normally do that this way...

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.Window',{
    title:msg,
    ....//
}).show();
```

And the method I mentioned before for accesing the windows fields will probably require it being created like this.